# How to resolve post 200 successful but new record not added to the tables, flash not displaying and not being redirected to the appropriate page

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

```
import re
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, flash, redirect, url_for
from flask import Blueprint
from db import db
from os import path
from models import Student, Studentreview, Admin, Cao, Lecturer, Lecturer_review, Cao_review
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
import segno


app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'gth_dhd11'
MAIN_DB = "database.db"
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = f'sqlite:///{MAIN_DB}'
db.init_app(app)



with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()
pattern = r'^[A-Z]{3}/\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{3}$'

registration_bp = Blueprint('registration_bp', __name__)
@registration_bp.route('/registration_success', methods=['GET'])
def registration_success():
    return render_template('registration_success.html')

@registration_bp.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    form = ''

    if request.method == 'POST':
        account_type = request.form.get('register-selector')
        if account_type == 'studentform':
            firstname = request.form.get('firstname')
            lastname = request.form.get('lastname')
            matricno = request.form.get('matricno')
            sex = request.form.get('sex')
            department = request.form.get('department')
            dorm = request.form.get('dorm')
            password1 = request.form.get('password1')
            password2 = request.form.get('password2')
        
            # Check if matricpattern is valid
            if not re.match(pattern, matricno):
                flash('Invalid matric number format', category='error')
            
            # Check if matricno already exists
            existing_student = Student.query.filter_by(matricno=matricno).first()
            if existing_student:
                flash('Matric Number already exists', category='error')
                
            if len(firstname) < 3:
                flash('Names must be greater than 2 chars', category="error")
            elif len(lastname) < 3:
                flash('Names must be greater than 2 chars', category="error")
            elif password1 != password2:
                flash('Passwords don\'t match', category="error")
            elif len(password1) < 7:
                flash('Password too short, at least 7 chars', category="error")
            else:
                password = request.form.get('password1')
                hashed_password = generate_password_hash(password)
                new_student = Studentreview(firstname=firstname, lastname=lastname, matricno=matricno, sex=sex, department=department, dorm=dorm ,password=hashed_password)
                db.session.add(new_student)
                db.session.commit()
                # Generate QR code
                qr = segno.make(str(new_student.id))
                qr_image = qr.png(scale=10)
                new_student.qr_code = qr_image
                db.session.commit()
                flash('Account Queued!, visit the admin to Complete your registration', category="success")
                form = 'studentform'
                
            return redirect(url_for('registration_bp.registration_success'))
            
        elif account_type == 'lecturerform':
            username = request.form.get('username')
            lastname = request.form.get('lastname')
            title = request.form.get('title')
            department = request.form.get('department')
            password1 = request.form.get('password1')
            password2 = request.form.get('password2')
                
                # Check if username already exists
            existing_lecturer = Lecturer.query.filter_by(username=username).first()
            if existing_lecturer:
                flash('Username already exists', category='error')
                

                if len(username) < 3:
                    flash('Username too short', category="error")
                elif len(lastname) < 3:
                    flash('Names must be greater than 2 chars', category="error")
                elif password1 != password2:
                    flash('Passwords don\'t match', category="error")
                elif len(password1) < 7:
                    flash('Password too short, atleast 7 chars', category="error")
                else:
                    password = request.form.get('password1')
                    hashed_password = generate_password_hash(password)

                    new_lecturer = Lecturer_review(username=username, lastname=lastname, title=title, department=department, password=hashed_password)
                    db.session.add(new_lecturer)
                    db.session.commit()
                    registration_success()
                    flash('Account Created Successfully!', category="success")
                    form = 'lecturerform'
                    
                return redirect(url_for('registration_bp.registration_success'))
        
        elif account_type == 'caoform':
             # Code for cao registration
            username = request.form.get('username')
            lastname = request.form.get('lastname')
            title = request.form.get('title')
            password1 = request.form.get('password1')
            password2 = request.form.get('password2')
             # Check if username already exists
            existing_cao = Cao.query.filter_by(username=username).first()
            if existing_cao:
                flash('Username already exists', category='error')

            if len(firstname) < 3:
                flash('Firstname must be greater than 2 chars', category="error")
            elif len(lastname) < 3:
                flash('Lastname must be greater than 2 chars', category="error")
            elif password1 != password2:
                flash('Passwords don\'t match', category="error")
            elif len(password1) < 7:
                flash('Password too short, at least 7 chars', category="error")
            else:
                password = request.form.get('password1')
                hashed_password = generate_password_hash(password)
                new_cao = Cao_review(username=username, lastname=lastname, title=title , password=hashed_password)
                db.session.add(new_cao)
                db.session.commit()
                flash('Account Created Successfully!', category="success")
                form = 'caoform'
                
            return redirect(url_for('registration_bp.registration_success'))
        
        
    return render_template('register.html', form=form)

app.register_blueprint(registration_bp, methods=['GET', 'POST'])

if __name__ =="__main__":
    app.run('127.0.0.1', debug=True)
```

This is the route for the register page. i made sure the names of my forms match, theres also a showform function written with javascript but that works well hence why its not in this code. I want to add the models for my tables too but i cant. The issue mostly is the page load, when i fill the forms and press the submit button, the page just reloads instead of redirecting me to the registration_success page or at least show the flash messages. So i suspect the function isnt working as expected, but just cant figure why, remember post 200 is displaying in the terminal whenever i press the submit button.

```
                                
{% include '_flashes.html' %}


                                <div class="customboot">
                            <div class="container d-flex justify-content-center align-centent">       
              <div class="customselect">
            <div class="form-floating">
                              
              <select class="form-select" id="register-selector" onchange="showForm()">
                                
                                <option value="studentform">Student</option>
                                <option value="lecturerform" >Lecturer</option>
                                <option value="caoform">CA-Officer</option>
                                
                            
                              </select>
                            </div>
              </div>
                
                 
                      
                      
                      <form name="studentform" class="border shadow p-3 rounded"  method="POST", id="studentform" action="{{ url_for('registration_bp.register') }}">
                        <h4>Student Registration form</h4>
                                      <div class="mb-3">
                                       
                                        <input type="text" 
                                        class="form-control" 
                                        name="firstname"
                                        id="firstname1" 
                                        
                                        placeholder="First Name">
                                      </div>

                                       <div class="mb-3">
                                        
                                        <input type="text" 
                                        class="form-control" 
                                        name="lastname"
                                        id="lastname1" 
                                        
                                        placeholder="Last Name">
                                        
                                      </div>
                                      
                                     
                                     <div class="mb-3">
                                       
                                        <input type="text" 
                                        class="form-control" 
                                        name="matricno"
                                        id="matricno" 
                                        
                                        placeholder="ABC/1234/12/123">
                                        
                                              </div>
                                                
                                                
                                                  
                                    
                                    <div class="mb-3">
                                        
                                      <select id="sex1" name="sex">
                                        <option disabled selected value="">Sex</option>
                                        <option value="Male">male</option>
                                         <option value="Female">female</option>
                                      </select>
                                      </div>
                      
                                       <div class="mb-3">
                                       
                                        <input type="text" 
                                        class="form-control" 
                                        name="department"
                                        id="departmemt1" 
                                        
                                        placeholder="Department">
                                        
                                      </div>
                                      
                                      <div class="mb-3">
                                       
                      
                                      <select id="dorm" name="dorm">
                                        <option disabled selected value="">Dorm</option>
                                        <option value="kaaf1up">KAAF1 Up</option>
                                        <option value="kaaf1down">KAAF1 Down</option>
                                         <option value="kaaf2up">KAAF2 Up</option>
                                         <option value="kaaf2down">KAAF2 Down</option>
                                         <option value="lagcen-up">Lagos Central Up</option>
                                         <option value="lagcen-down">Lagos Central Down</option>

                                      </select>
                                      </div>




                                      <div class="mb-3">
                                        
                                        <input type="password" 
                                        class="form-control" 
                                        name="password1"
                                        id="password1"
                                        placeholder="Password">
                                        
                                          </div>
                      
                                           <div class="mb-3">
                                       
                                        <input type="password" 
                                        class="form-control" 
                                        name="password2"
                                        id="password2" 
                                        
                                        placeholder="Confirm Password">
                                        
                                      </div>
                                      
                                      
                                      <button type="submit"  
                                      class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                              
                        </form>
                      
                      
                                  <form name="lecturerform" class="border shadow p-3 rounded" method="POST" id="lecturerform" action="{{ url_for('registration_bp.register') }}" style="display: none;">
                                    <h4>Lecturer Registration form</h4>
                                    <div class="mb-3">
                                      
                                      <input type="text" 
                                      class="form-control" 
                                      name="username"
                                      id="username1" 
                                      placeholder="Username">
                                      
                                      
                                    </div>
                      
                                     <div class="mb-3">
                                      
                                      <input type="text" 
                                      class="form-control" 
                                      name="lastname"
                                      id="lastname2" 
                                      placeholder="Last Name">
                                      
                                      
                                    </div>
                             
                                  <div class="mb-3">
                                     
                      
                                    <select id="title1" name="title">
                                      <option value="" disabled selected>Title</option>
                                      <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
                                       <option value="Miss/Mrs">Miss/Mrs</option>
                                    </select>
                                    </div>
                      
                                     <div class="mb-3">
                                      
                                      <input type="text" 
                                      class="form-control" 
                                      name="department"
                                      id="departmemt2" 
                                      
                                      placeholder="Department">
                                      
                                    </div>
                                    
                                    
                                    <div class="mb-3">
                                     
                                      <input type="password" 
                                      class="form-control" 
                                      name="password1"
                                      id="password3"
                                      placeholder="Password">
                                        </div>
                      
                                         <div class="mb-3">
                                      
                                      <input type="password" 
                                      class="form-control" 
                                      name="password2"
                                      id="password4" 
                                      
                                      placeholder="Confirm Password">
                                      
                                    </div>
                                    
                                    
                                    <button type="submit"  
                                    class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

                            </form>
                              


                                <form name="caoform" class="border shadow p-3 rounded" method="POST" id="caoform" action="{{ url_for('registration_bp.register') }}" style="display: none;">
                                  <div class="mb-3">
                                    <h4>C-A Officer Registration form</h4>
                                    <input type="text" 
                                    class="form-control" 
                                    name="username"
                                    id="username2" 
                                    placeholder="Username">
                                   
                                    
                                  </div>
                                   <div class="mb-3">
                                   
                                    <input type="text" 
                                    class="form-control" 
                                    name="lastname"
                                    id="lastname3"
                                    placeholder="Last Name"> 
                                    
                                    
                                  </div>
                                  
                                 
                                
                                            
                                            
                                              
                                
                                <div class="mb-3">
                                    
                      
                                  <select id="title2" name="title">
                                    <option selected disabled value="">Title</option>
                                    <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
                                     <option value="Miss/Mrs">Miss/Mrs</option>
                                  </select>
                                  </div>
                      
                                  
                                  
                                  <div class="mb-3">
                                    
                                    <input type="password" 
                                    class="form-control" 
                                    name="password1"
                                    id="password5"
                                    placeholder="Password">
                                      </div>
                      
                                       <div class="mb-3">
                                    
                                    <input type="password" 
                                    class="form-control" 
                                    name="password2"
                                    id="password6" 
                                    
                                    placeholder="Confirm Password">
                                    
                                  </div>
                                  
                                  
                                      <button type="submit"  
                                      class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                              </form>
                    
                    
                            </div>
                               
                  </div>       
        
    </body>
```